# PageMethod not found when using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

well, i'm trying to retrieve info from a PageMethod using jquery and ajax, and so far i handn't had any luck

While debuging the whole thing, i found that my error part was launching, then i used the debugger of VS and didnt got any info, but with Firebug i found out the method wasn't being found, given a Internal Server Error was thrown

Here's my aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="RutaLecturista.aspx.vb" Inherits="LocalLecturas.RutaLecturista" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ruta Lecturista</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="../Estilo.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var map; 
        var trazoRuta = new Array();

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            inicializar();
        });

        function inicializar()
        {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.082807, -110.928197);
            var myOptions = 
            {
                zoom: 12,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            extraerDatos();
        }

        function extraerDatos()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'RutaLecturista.aspx/obtenerCoordenadas',
                data: '{}',
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                succes: function(xml)
                {
                    crearMarca(xml);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error al consultar el servicioWeb: ' + errorThrown + ' ' + textStatus + ' ' + XMLHttpRequest);
                    $("#errmsg").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings)
                    {
                        $(this).append("<li>Error al extraer los datos " + settings.url + "</li>");
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        function crearMarca(xml)
        {
            try
            {
                alert('Datos obtenidos!!!');
                $(xml).find('Table').each(function()
                {
                    var lat = $(this).find('Latitud').text();
                    var lon = $(this).find('Longitud').text();
                    var certeza = $(this).find('Precision').text();
                    var titulo = $(this).find('F_Actual').text();
                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
                    trazoRuta.push(location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        position: location, 
                        map: map
                    });
                    marker.setTitle(titulo);
                    var circuloCerteza;
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() 
                    {
                        var populationOptions = 
                        {
                            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            fillColor: "#FF0000",
                            fillOpacity: 0.35,
                            map: map,
                            center: location,
                            radius: certeza / 2
                        };
                        circuloCerteza = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
                    });            
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() 
                    {
                        circuloCerteza.setMap(null)
                    });
                });
                trazoRuta.reverse();
                var ruta = new google.maps.Polyline(
                {
                    path: trazoRuta,
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });
                ruta.setMap(map);                
            }
            catch(err)
            {
            }
        }

        function getQueryVariable(variable)
        {
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++)
            {
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                if (pair[0] == variable)
                {
                    return pair[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }

        /*function crearMarca(titulo, lat, lon, certeza)
        {
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: location, 
                map: map
            });
            marker.setTitle(titulo);
            var circuloCerteza;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() 
            {
                var populationOptions = 
                {
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#FF0000",
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,
                    map: map,
                    center: location,
                    radius: certeza / 2
                };
                circuloCerteza = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
            });            
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() 
            {
                circuloCerteza.setMap(null)
            });
        }    //*/      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%"></div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="errmsg" style="width: 244px">
        <asp:Label ID="Label_1" runat="server">No hay Coordendas para esta Ruta</asp:Label>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
<%--        <asp:GridView ID="gvCoordenadas" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
                GridLines="None" CssClass="REPORTE">
                <FooterStyle CssClass="REPORTE_FooterStyle" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="REPORTE_RowStyle " />  
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Latitud" HeaderText="Latitud" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Longitud" HeaderText="Longitud" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="F_ACTUAL" HeaderText="Fecha" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
--%>    
        </div>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the codeBehind code

```
Partial Public Class RutaLecturista
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'If Session("USR") = Nothing Then
        '    Response.Redirect("../Acceso.aspx?dato=No tiene acceso en este sistema")
        'End If
        Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false""> </script>")
        'Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        'sb.Append("<script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"">")
        'Try
        '    Dim id_lec As String = Request.QueryString("id_lec").Substring(0, 10)
        '    Proceso.Fill_DataSet(DataSet, Consultas.obtenerLocalizacion(id_lec, "", "", ""), "Coordenadas" + id_lec)
        '    If DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        '        Label_1.Visible = False
        '        gvCoordenadas.DataSource = DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec)
        '        gvCoordenadas.DataBind()
        '        gvCoordenadas.Visible = True
        '        sb.Append("function crearMarcas(){" + vbNewLine)
        '        For Each linea As Data.DataRow In DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec).Rows
        '            sb.Append("crearMarca(""" + linea("F_Actual").ToString + """, " + linea("Latitud").ToString + ", " + linea("Longitud").ToString + ", " + linea("precision").ToString + ");" + vbNewLine)
        '        Next
        '        sb.Append("}" + vbNewLine)
        '        sb.Append("var trazoRuta = [" + vbNewLine)
        '        For contador As Integer = 0 To DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec).Rows.Count - 1
        '            sb.Append("new google.maps.LatLng(" + DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec).Rows(contador).Item("Latitud").ToString + ", " + DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec).Rows(contador).Item("Longitud").ToString + ")")
        '            If contador + 1 < DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec).Rows.Count Then
        '                sb.Append("," + vbNewLine)
        '            End If
        '        Next
        '        sb.Append("];" + vbNewLine)
        '    Else

        '    End If
        'Catch ex As Exception
        'End Try
        'sb.Append("</script>")
        'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ajax", sb.ToString(), False)
    End Sub

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Function obtenerCoordenadas() As String
        Dim datos As New Data.DataSet
        Dim resultado As String = ""
        Dim id_lec As String = Request.QueryString("id_lec").Substring(0, 10)
        Proceso.Fill_DataSet(datos, Consultas.obtenerLocalizacion(id_lec, "", "", ""), "Coordenadas" + id_lec)
        If DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            resultado = datos.GetXml
        End If
        Return resultado
    End Function

End Class
```

Hope i can get a answer quick, i'm running out of time, patience and ideas :S

Comment: You should try to reduce the amount of code to only what's relevant to the question. It's harder to get a quick answer when you have to read through so much code.

Comment: well, i posted the whole code because there are time when i post only the relevant part, then i see someone replied to my question and find out they are asking me for the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `obtenerCoordenadas()` method static.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function obtenerCoordenadas() As String
    Dim datos As New Data.DataSet
    Dim resultado As String = ""
    Dim id_lec As String = Request.QueryString("id_lec").Substring(0, 10)
    Proceso.Fill_DataSet(datos, Consultas.obtenerLocalizacion(id_lec, "", "", ""), "Coordenadas" + id_lec)
    If DataSet.Tables("Coordenadas" + id_lec).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        resultado = datos.GetXml
    End If
    Return resultado
End Function
```

Here's a great article on this exact topic by Dave Ward.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I think `static` might be called `Shared` in VB.NET. I'm more familar with C#.

Comment: yes, thanks, i forgot to add the Shared in the method definition, Man, such a silly error!!!!